# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Setup..\r\n'

Tags: python-3.9

I want to run my code using Arduino and Python. I have to write a script to fetch the data serially and save it into a CSV file. When I run the script I get this error `"ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Setup..\r\n'"`

```py
  import csv
  from time import time
  import serial 
  import numpy
  # Your serial port might be different!

  ser = serial.Serial('COM12',baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, timeout=1)

  f = open("df.csv", "a+")
  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
  while True:
    s = ser.readline().decode()
    if s != "":
      rows = [float(x) for x in s.split(',')]
      # Insert local time to list's first position
      rows.insert(0, int(time()))
      print(rows)
      writer.writerow(rows)
      f.flush()
```

Comment: Besides exception, make sure you break the loop properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip invalid lines with `try/except`:

```py
  ...
  s = ser.readline().decode()
  if s != "":
    try:
      rows = [float(x) for x in s.split(',')]
      rows.insert(0, int(time()))
      print(rows)
      writer.writerow(rows)
      f.flush()
    except ValueError:
      print('Invalid line')
  ...
```

or this way (no need to `try`):

```
rows = [float(x) for x in list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), a.split(',')))]
```

Comment: Hello Michael, I have tried like this, if I write a code like this, then it always shows me "Invalid line", I want to get my data which is sent by my Arduino., so if Instead of "Float if I write[ rows = [str(x) for x in s.split(',')]] or ["repr""] , then it will give me the output, but I think this is not the right way ? can you explain me here thank you

Comment: Try `filter` solution (see an updated answer)

Comment: ok as you told I have tried with the "filter" method , so now its showing like,[1621275345]
[1621275345]
[1621275345]
[1621275345]
[1621275345]
[1621275345]
[1621275345]
[1621275346]
[1621275347]
[1621275348]
[1621275349] 
[1621275350]
this value means I am getting only timing value, I am working on the temperature sensor and need those values as an output.

Comment: @Khangesh your question was about exception and I think I have answered it properly. Now you are asking a completely different question about interpretation of the converted values. The right and acceptable Stack Overflow way is to post another question and define your actual problem there instead of changing the subject of an answered post...

Comment: Yeah, I understand Michael, Pardon me, this is the first time I am using this platform, and I don't know the regulations here I will ask my question properly and, I will sort out this, and thanks a lot for your time and answers, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Hello Michael, one last question is it right way to write like this in python to get the strings                                                 " while True:
    s = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").rstrip()
    if s != '':
        rows = [repr(x) for x in s.split(',')]
        rows.insert(0, int(time()))
        print(rows)
        writer.writerow(rows)
        f.flush()
" If I did this I will get everything.

Comment: Hi. I don't have your input file and a proper environment to verify it's correct but it looks OK (at least I don't see any problem with your code). If it works it outputs a correct result, it's OK. If it foes not work for you, post a new question with all the necessary details.